# How do I make this inner div scroll vertically when needed?

Tags: html, css, layout

[image: layout]

This is my page layout. Everything should be flexible according to its content. As far it is working good, but when the content of the red area exceeds the page height, the whole page is scrollable (default behaviour). How do I make only the red div scrollable when its content exceeds?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML and CSS you have so far?

Comment: The `body` I have layed out with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` - so the header is as height as required, and the bottom (`div` holding green, yellow and red area) is stretched to 100%. Then on this holding `div`, I have `display: flex` again with same performance: green area is as wide as needed, and the right (`div` holding yellow and red area) is stretched to 100%. The yellow and red areas are just plain `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue previously, if I didn't set the height of the div, the scroll won't work, the div will expand dynamically in vertical if there are a lot of contents vertically. I used boostrap 4 css framework. 
Since you are not sharing your code, assuming you haven't set a height for your red area div. If you want to hardcode the overflow css, it will be like this:

```
<div id="red_area" style="height:70vh; overflow-y: scroll"> // The height here is just for example
```

But I suggest you create a custom css styling and assign a class to it. For example:

```
<div id="red_area" class="overflow-y-scroll height-70vh">
```

And in your custom css file add this:

```
.overflow-y-scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.height-70vh {
   height: 70vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I want the layout to be dynamic.

Comment: then how do you set in which height limit the `<div>` should scroll or not?

Comment: when its content exceeds the document's height - the whole page can be 100% height by default

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: fixed` will put an element on a fixed place relative to the browser window. The `html, body, #fixed` element must have `height: 100%`.

```
<body>
<div id="fixed">
  <div id="box1">
    box1
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
    box2
  </div>
  <div id="menu">
    menu<br>menu<br>menu
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  content 123<br>content 456<br>content 789
  <br>content 123<br>content 456<br>content 789
  <br>content 123<br>content 456<br>content 789
</div>
</body>

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
#fixed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
}
#box1 {
  height: 80px;
  background: #ff0;
}
#box2 {
  height: 30px;
  background: #0ff;
}
#menu {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background: #abc;
}
#content {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  padding-top: 110px; /* offset from top */
  background: #cba;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I want the layout to be dynamic.